# Create a page with database data in a module

Tags: database

I am new to drupal and in a process of developing a custom module. My module will do a couple of things:

1. (ADMIN) User will be able to select a zip file and upload it
2. (ADMIN) The module will than take that file, extract it to files folder
3. (ADMIN) Upload the content from a certain file to the database table
4. (ADMIN/front end) Create a link/page/node on the front page in navigation where the data will be displayed with some additional js required

I got first 3 things going but I am struggeling with the last one.

Any pointers in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all the uploaded Zips contain similar data you could expose the custom table to Views using hook_views_data and then make a View path with a contextual filter to show the content of a given table.

If you really need a link look at the hook_menu function and make a menu entry that loads a custom page ... which can then load a custom View to show your data on a page.